# r creating a confusion matrix using by variable

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I would like to create multiple confusion matrices from one `dataframe` which contains a categorical variable (`df$park`) defining how I would like the matrices summarized.

Here is my data:

```
df <- structure(list(park = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("miss", 
"piro"), class = "factor"), co1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("false", "true"), class = "factor"), co2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("false", "true"), class = "factor"), 
    UNIQUE = structure(c(2L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
    20L, 21L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L
    ), .Label = c("10066_109_2010", "1012008_ 2008", "10269_7_2006", 
    "10332008_ 2008", "10588_51_2006", "10628_46_2008", "10642006_ 2006", 
    "10683_26_2006", "1072010_ 2010", "10749_1_2009", "10750_1_2010", 
    "10802_6_2006", "10841_43_2006", "10902_19_2006", "10921_37_2006", 
    "1102007_ 2007", "1102008_ 2008", "1102010_ 2010", "11142006_ 2006", 
    "1172007_ 2007", "1232010_ 2010"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("park", 
"co1", "co2", "UNIQUE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Looks like...

```
> head (df)
  park   co1   co2         UNIQUE
1 miss false false  1012008_ 2008
2 miss false false 10332008_ 2008
3 miss false false 10642006_ 2006
4 miss false false  1072010_ 2010
5 miss false false  1102007_ 2007
6 miss false false  1102008_ 2008
```

I can quickly and easily create a confusion matrix which shows how `co1` and `co2` agree and disagree (true vs false)....

```
conf <- table(df$co1,df$co2)
conf

    false true
  false    13    3
  true      3    2
```

But I would like the trues and falses summarized by `df$park`, which would create a table for each factor present in `df$park`.

Any ideas?

Thanks
-al

EDIT 1:
@won782 is correct, this code works....

```
conf <- table (df[,3:1])

> conf
, , park = miss

       co1
co2     false true
  false     8    0
  true      0    2

, , park = piro

       co1
co2     false true
  false     5    3
  true      3    0
```

But now I need to preserve this formatting and output to a csv file.

EDIT 2:

Using `as.data.frame(table (df[,3:1]))` doesn't preserve the nice cross table. This is what `as.data.frame` produces.

```
> conf.df <- as.data.frame(table(df[,3:1]))
> conf.df
     co2   co1 park Freq
1  false false miss   50
2   true false miss    1
3  false  true miss    3
4   true  true miss   27
5  false false piro  390
6   true false piro   64
7  false  true piro   17
8   true  true piro   81
9  false false sacn  222
10  true false sacn   14
11 false  true sacn    3
12  true  true sacn   58
13 false false slbe  340
14  true false slbe   65
15 false  true slbe   33
16  true  true slbe  18
```

EDIT 3:
I decided to do a `for` loop instead.

```
lev <- levels (df$park)
for (p in lev){
g <- df[which(df$park==p),]
test <- table(g$co1,g$co2)
write.csv(test,(paste("c:\temp\","confuse_",p,".csv",sep='')),row.names=F)
}
```

EDIT 4:
To capture the exact format of the table output, I found that you can `capture` it and send it to a text file. It would be better if `capture` and output it as a csv, but my attempts at this have produced csv files that aren't very readable. This is my solution for capturing it and sending it to a text file.

```
lev <- levels (df$park)
for (p in lev){
g <- df[which(df$park==p),]
test <- table(g$co1,g$co2)
out <- capture.output(test)
cat(out,file=paste("c:\temp\","confuse_",p,".txt",sep=""),sep="\n",append=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I think this will solve the problem (If I understood your question correctly). `table(df[, 3:1])`

Comment: Would `as.data.frame(table(df[,3:1]))` help to for saving as csv?

Comment: @beginneR, see my second edit above. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I know that by using `as.data.frame()` those tables will be converted to a single data.frame. But I was trying to say that this might make it easier to save the information in a csv or other spreadsheet. There may be other options but I don't know how to save multiple tables like in your case.

Comment: I should probably just create a function to loop through each level in `df$park`, create a table, and output the table as csv.